# BottomNavigation not going to my fragment icon when start

Tags: java, android

I have a BottomNavigation that shows a couple of items, with this code I managed to start the BottomNavigation at a desired item

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_content, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
```

which is my ProfileFragment.

When it starts its inflating that Fragment and thats its ok, but the slider below is not selecting the tab it should be

How can I update both things ?

Comment: paste your activity code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about `BottomNavigationView`, i.e. `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` and in that case, I can say that it works almost like a Menu and its state (selection) can be maintained manually like one.

Specifically to your questions, you can use

> BottomNavigationView#setSelectedItemId(@IdRes int itemId)